# How to Color particular item of combobox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I want to color all **"Unselectable"** Text from combo box. How can i do this? I tried it but i am unable to do this.

My Code is Given Below:

```
private class ComboBoxItem
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool Selectable { get; set; }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
    this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
    this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new[] {
        new ComboBoxItem() { Selectable = true, Text="Selectable0", Value=0,  },
        new ComboBoxItem() { Selectable = true, Text="Selectable1", Value=1},
        new ComboBoxItem() { Selectable = true, Text="Selectable2", Value=2},
        new ComboBoxItem() { Selectable = false, Text="Unselectable", Value=3},
        new ComboBoxItem() { Selectable = true, Text="Selectable3", Value=4},
        new ComboBoxItem() { Selectable = false, Text="Unselectable", Value=5},
    });

    this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += (cbSender, cbe) =>
    {
        var cb = cbSender as ComboBox;

        if (cb.SelectedItem != null && cb.SelectedItem is ComboBoxItem && ((ComboBoxItem)cb.SelectedItem).Selectable == false)
        {
            // deselect item
            cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
    };
}
```

I am working in C#.NET.

Comment: `I tried it but `, no you haven't. Nowhere in your code you're changing the color of an item. All you're doing is setting the selected index to -1 (no item) when an unselectable item is selected.

Comment: Well I guess he hopes for something automagical. Where do you change the Text or the bool Selectable properties?? This would be the place to look for, if it shall work dynamically..

Comment: Did you resolve your problems?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `ComboBox.DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawxxx` and script the `DrawItem` event e.g. like this:

```
 private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
 {

    e.DrawBackground();
     // skip without valid index
    if (e.Index >= 0) 
    {
      ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)comboBox1.Items[e.Index];
      Graphics g = e.Graphics;
      Brush brush =  new SolidBrush(e.BackColor);
      Brush tBrush = new SolidBrush(cbi.Text == "Unselectable" ? Color.Red : e.ForeColor);

      g.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
      e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font,
                 tBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
      brush.Dispose();
      tBrush.Dispose();
    }
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();

 }
```

This part `cbi.Text == "Unselectable"` is not good, obviously. Since you already have a Property `Selectable` it should really read  `!cbi.Selectable"` . Of course you must make sure that the property is in synch with the text.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the foreground property on the ComboBoxItem to the colour you require.

```
new ComboBoxItem() { Selectable = false, Text="Unselectable", Value=3, Foreground = Brushes.Red},
```

[MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.comboboxitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Despite the name `ComboBoxItem` this is `Winforms` and his custom class has none of the WPF's `ComboBoxItem`'s features.