# 'Nice' options style winforms dialog control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-experience

Here and there I've seen nicely styled dialog controls, similar to this one which appears in Beyond Compare v4:

[image]

My own implementation of this gets vaguely close, and consists of a listbox on the left and usercontrols which change when the listbox selected item changes.  However no amount of putting lipstick on that pig will get it looking like the above.  I can picture how I might undertake this with custom painting of things and so forth, but my real intent is to generate the left hand entries at runtime not design time (there will be one for each column in a datafile).

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to reasonably easily implement such a thing, either with a component (commercial is fine) or some other ingenious method.

Thanks!

Comment: Waiting for the first "Better use WPF" comments to arrive...

Comment: Hint: [DevExpress](http://devexpress.com) or [Telerik](http://telerik.com) or [Infragistics](http://infragistics.com) or...

Comment: If you want to mimick that in Winforms the 1st thing do do is replace the ListBox by a ListView. Actually one should do that almost all the time anyway.. You probably will have to owner-draw it, but don't worry - doing that is no rocket science! Many posts out there that will help you like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228379/listview-control-like-in-windows-explorer/24229846#24229846) one or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569436/how-to-color-particular-item-of-combobox/24598785#24598785) one..

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I have looked at those major component suites and don't see anything 'out of the box' that looks that way.  The idea of using a listview instead of a listbox is a great scheme.

Comment: Isn't this roughly what you're talking about? https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1637 (I've used DevExpress WinForms stuff a lot and can generally recommend it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of mimicking your design. I have one large `panel1` to house both sides and in it one `panel2` to house the left side. Inside `panel2` there are the search controls and the `listview`.

The search controls are a `Label1` containing a `TextBox` and another `Label2`. The `Label.Images` are aligned and the `Textbox` has no Border. The `Labels` are `AutoSize=false` and `Label1` has a 3D-border.

`Panel1` has a singleLine border, `panel2` and the `ListView` have no borders. The `ListView` has `View=Details` and one column, `HeaderStyle=None`. It also has `OwnerDraw=true`.

I have added a `Paint` event for the `ListView` but have to call it in code.

Please note that I haven't taken the time to create nice images. Also note: Their height will determine the Items' Height (!) so leave a little transparent border above and below; their good looks will be key to the overall looks!

They are contained in an `Imagelist` with appropriate `Size` and `BitDepth`. You may need to adapt the `DrawIamge` numbers..

The stuff on the right side is pretty much standard; for the horizontal bar I use a `Panel` with `height=1` and `Border=Single`. If you have more than one group of `RadioButtons` make sure to put each group in a separate Panel, transparent and no Borders, of course..

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    listView1.Width = panel2.ClientSize.Width;
    listView1.Columns[0].Width = listView1.ClientSize.Width;
    listView1.Paint += listView1_Paint;
    listView1.BackColor = panel2.BackColor;
    leftBrush = new SolidBrush(panel2.BackColor);
    rightBrush = new SolidBrush(panel1.BackColor);
}

Pen borderPen = new Pen(SystemColors.ActiveBorder);
SolidBrush leftBrush, rightBrush;

private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ItemIndex == 0)  listView1_Paint(
        null, new PaintEventArgs(e.Graphics, listView1.ClientRectangle)); 

    if (!e.Item.Selected)
    {
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(leftBrush, e.Bounds);
      e.Graphics.DrawLine(borderPen, 
                 listView1.Width-1, e.Bounds.Y, listView1.Width-1, e.Bounds.Bottom);
    }
    else
    {
       e.Graphics.FillRectangle(rightBrush , e.Bounds);
       e.Graphics.DrawLine(borderPen, 0, e.Bounds.Top, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Top);
       e.Graphics.DrawLine(borderPen, 
                           0, e.Bounds.Bottom-1, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Bottom-1);
    }
    e.Graphics.DrawString( e.Item.Text, listView1.Font, 
                          Brushes.Black, 35, e.Bounds.Y + 5 );
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList1.Images[e.Item.ImageIndex], 2, e.Bounds.Y );
}

void listView1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int hh = listView1.Items.Count * imageList1.ImageSize.Height;
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(borderPen, 
               listView1.Width - 1, hh, listView1.Width - 1, listView1.Height);
}

private void panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(borderPen, panel2.Width-1, 0, panel2.Width-1, listView1.Top);
}
```

}

Here is a screenshot of my Q&D version:

[image: 'Nice' Options Dialog]]

Comment: This looks fantastic TaW!  Exactly what I had in mind.  I'm trying to replicate it (particularly the idea of having a label with a textbox inside it lost me a bit).  Would you mind posting the .desigher.cs file or making a .zip link available?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Here you go:[Form](http://www.file-upload.net/download-9510371/Form1.zip.html) and [Designer](http://www.file-upload.net/download-9510366/Form1.Designer.cs.zip.html), a (slightly) modified version

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for that.  If you happen to see this, I'd love to hear your comments on the 'textbox inside a label' idea.  I haven't come across that and would be interested in the reasons for that approach :)

Comment: The Label is a versatile and much underrated control. I used it here simply as a cheap way to add two images to the design and I put the TextBox and the 2nd Label inside the 1st one to keep them all together and also to have them inside a 3D border. Most Controls can have other Controls added to their Controls collection, but most of the time it doesn't make much sense..

Comment: The TextBox control doesn't support a Padding, so I couldn't add the Images (via Labels) to it without interferring with the text in the box. The Label otoh has Padding and you can use it to fine-tune the position of the Images in them..

Comment: Superb - I appreciate the extra details TaW!  I'll try that technique.